die with 555, 4017 and 4026 need extra pulse after reset
I was thinking of making a die that runs somehow from 1 to 6. Using a decade counter it resets after reaching > 6. But the problem is at that point the pulses from the digital clock may still flow but I need it to for sure hit one pulse right after reset, otherwise it will display a zero. It has to be directly after resetting because if the button is released after 6 it should go to displaying 1, not 0. How to do this?

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab

Yeah. It's easy enough. You don't want to use an MCU?

No the challenge I came up was is doing it without an MCU. MCU is not a challenge...
I don't really get the answer from the link though...

well what i hoped for was that using some kind of RC circuit in between it could be solved, but if not, i am open for suggestions.

The 4017B and 4022B are decade and octal counters. That's not what you want. What's the voltage supply? Do you have to have 3-18 V range of operation?

it is 4017 (decade counter) and 4026 is drive a 7 segment lcd display (the old well known '8-module'), voltage sure can be in that range, i will be using a 555 times for the pulses, putting it anywhere about 1 kHz should give semi random results when i push the button briefly.

the power supply can be anything suitable for what is necessary, 5 volt only for example would work for me... but if there is a solution that needs 12 volt, sure I can work with that, or even use voltage regulators if multiple voltages are needed

the 4013 flipflop thing sounds promising, no idea how to use it in this regard, though... :)

i have the 4026 to drive the 7-seg display, but indeed, for the logic it does not matter, i just reset them at the same time... only that initial pulse from 0 to 1 at the decade counter right after reset is my problem, and how do i prevent it to be simultaneous with a pulse from the 555...

Do you want numbers on LED 7-segment display or what? Use something else, like a presettable counter and 7-seg driver. Or seven LEDs arranged like on a real die, I believe such circuit is at least 40 years old.

yes i want numbers on the LED 7-segment display... but i could have asked the question only showing the clock and the decade counter... the question is about the initial (extra) pulse after reset, either during button pressed or right after release

Tip: die (singular), dice (plural). You're making a single die.

@Niels Here's the direction I was considering. Counter and decoder are combined to directly drive the display. (Shown with NAND-only [single SKU] or with AND/OR mix.)

trying to add an extra pulse seems tricky, and possibly could cause timing problem between the two chips. probably best to avoid that.
Instead of the 4026 use a counter that has a preload (set to 1) combined with a binary-to-7 segment chip.
for example you could use 4510 and 4511
